# Is Servlet-based Spring MVC stack becoming obsolete with WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I am currently struggling with choosing between the Servlet-based MVC stack and the newer reactive WebFlux stack for a new Spring Boot - based project. I know for sure that I won't be needing the scalability benefits that the WebFlux model brings, so the added complexity that reactive programming and learning the Reactor API etc. brings with it does not seem warranted. Also I wouldn't want to lock myself out of being able to use JPA which doesn't play nice with WebFlux. Even though I'll probalby go for a simpler data access API like Spring Data JDBC / R2DBC, I'd like to keep options open.

The only thing I am unsure about is to what extent the traditional Servlet stack can be considered future proof. I would imagine that maintaining two separate web stacks that basically do the same thing is not something the community is keen on doing indefinitely. On the other hand, I can see my application have a lifespan of at least 10 years, maybe much longer. So if it were to outlive the underlying stack, it would have to be at least partially rewritten at some point, or become yet another piece dreaded legacy code.

Any thoughts on that? Are my fears about the long-term future of the Servlet stack unfounded? Or should I bite the bullet and go with WebFlux even if it means higher development cost with no short-term customer benefits?

Comment: You're worrying 10 years into the future about an application that hasn't written yet. The world will be a nuclear graveyard by that time more likely than the Servlet stack being completely out of use, so I wouldn't sweat it that much.

Comment: In 10 years time Project Loom will likely be available which will make Servlet API as good option as WebFlux even from performance perspective. I would rather expect WebFlux to become obsolete at that time.

Comment: That's an interesting perspective, I never thought about it that way, but it makes sense. If threads become as cheap as event-driven concurrency, there probably isn't much point to reactive programming any more. [Brian Goetz thinks so too](https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/oxcoeq/brian_goetz_i_think_project_loom_is_going_to_kill/), so that makes this perspective even more compelling :-)